# Show AJAX success JSON values in html selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have html form with few drop down selections, i used same form for editing data,

Now to edit data in any row of table, i had created AJAX request, once row is selected and user click on edit, AJAX get all values of that specific row with ID.

My html form have some input elements and select element, 
I can show value in input element with below code,

in my html element with id - `user_name` is input type, so i can see data value in box,

But element with id - `user_status` is selection type, where i have options Enable and Disable,

```
      success:function(data){   
        var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);           
        $("#user_name").val(objData.user_name);
        $("#user_status").val(objData.user_status);
      }
```

This is my HTML select code,

```
  <select name="is_manager" id="user_status">
      <option style="width:auto">--Select Status--?</option>
      <option style="width:auto">Enable</option>
      <option style="width:auto">Disable</option>
  </select>
```

How can i show AJAX return value ENABLE in selection option when i click Edit row, In short i want to see existing value in selection element.

Thanks,

Comment: In your json, you are getting text value or some id's as well for options?

Comment: Hello Vaibhav, I am getting tex value, like if user is enable then i get user_status: 'Enable'

Comment: can't you access it directly as- `data.user_name`?

Comment: @Manoz, i have no issue with #user_name, because its text box, i can simply assign value with .val(), but i could not assign to selection option,

Comment: So while creating the options, you can set the value property of the option as same as label property like <option style="width:auto" value="Enable">Enable</option> now in you success function you can set the value the way you are setting.

Comment: @Vaibhav, but where should i put id for assigning value, should it be in select element or in option?

Comment: which id? are you getting 'id' as well for the options? If yes then you can set  'id' inside your ajax function. And if you have 'id' in dropdown and from server side you are getting only value then tell me, I can give a code snippet for that

Comment: @Vaibhav, i am talking about element id in which this value will get assigned, id="user_status" example i can see AJAX success value in input element with below code <input type="text" name="firstname" id="user_name"> but i am struggling with select\options. Also give me snippet for server side ids as well, as i have few other forms when i get DB id for view in form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added option value in below selection list which are same as option Text

`<select name="is_manager" id="user_status">
      <option style="width:auto" value="">--Select Status--?</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Enable">Enable</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Disable">Disable</option>
  </select>`

And then in jquery you can use below code to set existing value as selected

`$("#user_status option[value="+objData.user_status+"]").attr("selected","selected")`

Hope this helps you

Comment: logically it seems fine but it seems not working, i get below message in console, jQuery.fn.attr('selected') may use property instead of attribute, any thoughts?

Comment: can you try ``.prop("selected",true)`` instead of  ``attr("selected","selected")``  ?. May be due to jquery version issue you getting that error message.

Comment: Thanks, now there is no message in console but still i not getting Enable as selected,---- my question, where this ID should kept, id="user_status", should it be in select element or in option element?

Comment: It should be set to select statement and not to option element.  Jquery will find the selection list based on ``#user_status``  id and then will look for its option values (``Enable,Disable``) and if any one of these option value matches with json output data (``objData.user_status``) then it will mark it as selected.  Make sure that  ``user_status`` id not used for any other element on page

Comment: I fully understood logic, i checked ID as well, not assigned to other elements, i did check with other pages as well, but what so ever reason, it seems "selected" property is not applied to option element, i always get first entry\value of option in drop down when i click on edit.

Comment: Can check what output you are getting for code ``("#user_status option[value="+objData.user_status+"]")``  (withoug $ symbol) using console.log  under success response section in you js code and share the output ??

Comment: i got ->  #user_status option[value=Enable]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73151/discussion-between-sameer-k-and-rjcode).

Comment: Hi Sameer, i did check in chrome, i found below, when page loads my select item show <option value="Enable">Enable</option>, then i use .attr() function, and it changed to <option value="Enable" selected="selected">Enable</option>, but still this Enable value not visible as selected in dropdown, with .prop(), its not appending Selected="selected"

Comment: Final found solution, issue was created due to bootstrap-select.js, this was showing strange selection values eventhough there was selected=selected was applied! realy strange....BTW, thanks it worked now, only think is now i have ugly dropdown ;-) i will see how to solve this bootstrap-select.js issue.

Comment: I think this link ``http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/``  might help you. You need to render the select list after updating the values.

Answer (score 0):

I am saying it would be good if you have some value property set for all the options like

```
 <select name="is_manager" id="user_status">
      <option style="width:auto" value="0">--Select Status--?</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="1">Enable</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="2">Disable</option>
  </select>
```

Then if you get value as '1' or '2' from the server side then you can use the way you have written `$("#user_status").val(objData.user_status);`

If you are getting only text as 'Enable' or 'Disable' then you can use

```
var user_status = $('#user_status);
    user_status.val(user_status.find('option: contains('+objData.user_status+')').val()));
```

If you are not using value property then create value property in options like

```
<select name="is_manager" id="user_status">
      <option style="width:auto" value="0">--Select Status--?</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Enable">Enable</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Disable">Disable</option>
  </select>
```

Now in this case you normal code which you have written will work.

Comment: Its not working, i got below message in console, Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option: contains(Disable)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
$('#user_status>option[value="'+objData.user_status+'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="is_manager" id="user_status">
      <option style="width:auto" value="0">--Select Status--?</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Enable">Enable</option>
      <option style="width:auto" value="Disable">Disable</option>
  </select>
```